# Difference in the execution of the loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

Can anyone explain me the difference in the execution of both of the codes?

1)

```
  #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    string code;
    getline(cin,code);
    for(int i=0;i<code.length();i++){
        if(code[i]=='.'){
            code.replace(i,1,"[.]");
        }
    }
    cout<<code;
    return 0;
}
```

The output screen of the above program code shows "time limit exceeded".

```
Time limit exceeded #stdin #stdout 5s 5220KB
```

2. 

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    string code;
    getline(cin,code);
    for(int i=0;i<code.length();i++){
        if(code[i]=='.'){
            code.replace(i,1,"[.]");
            i++;
        }
    }
    cout<<code;
    return 0;
}
```

whereas no.2 code shows the output as desired.

```
1[.]1[.]1[.]1
```

Can anyone explain how the execution took in both of the cases that one of the output shows "TLE"(the iteration count has to be declared in the for loop itself) and whereas the other one displays the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this and see what happens, for example with this input:

```
code = "google.com"
```

After a while, `i` will be equal to 6, and then it happens:

```
i          code
6          google[.]com     (and now there's a dot on place 7)
7          google[[.]]com   (and now there's a dot on place 8)
8          google[[[.]]]com (and now there's a dot on place 9)
...        ...
```

And there is no way to stop this.

As the replacement makes the place of the dot shift one to the right, it might be a good idea to have a for-loop in the other sense:

```
for(int i=code.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
```

Comment: Thanks!I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

In this loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<code.length();i++){
        if(code[i]=='.'){
            code.replace(i,1,"[.]");
        }
    }
```

when you do a replacement of `[.]`, in the next iteration of the loop `i` is now the index of the `.` that you just inserted. That `.` will be replaced again, and so on, infinitely many times, leading to a "time limit exceeded".

In the 2nd version, when a replacement is done, `i` is correctly being moved to point to the `]` instead. You could move it one step further as well, since you know there is no `.` at that position either.

Comment: does that mean the replace function is just working over and over again on the 1st index(the first ' . ') but not getting incremented but as I used "i++",the index increments and proceeds for the next check,please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Why don't you try `cout << code;` inside the loop? That should help you understand what's going on.

Comment: @sup  No problem. Just FYI, you can only accept one answer, so choose which one (if any) you found the most helpful. You can upvote multiple answers if you want. You can also use the "thanks" option :)